# Scala: Abstract Types in Class Parameters

Tags: scala, types

Quite simply, is there any way to marry constructor arguments and abstract types?  For example, something I would like to do

```
class A(t: Seq[T]) {
   type T
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The members of the class aren't in scope in the parameter declaration of the constructor.

This is as close as you can get:

```
scala> trait T { type T; val a: T }
defined trait T

scala> def A[X](x: X) = new T { type T = X; val a = x }
A: [X](x: X)Object with T{type T = X}

scala> A[Int](0)
res0: Object with T{type T = Int} = $anon$1@3bd29ee4

scala> A[String](0)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: String
              A[String](0)
                        ^
scala> class AA[X](val a: X) extends T { type T = X }
defined class AA

scala> new AA[Int](0)
res5: AA[Int] = AA@1b3d4787

scala> new AA[String](0)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch; 
  found   : Int(0) 
  required: String              
      new AA[String](0)              
                     ^
```

Comment: I am not sure about this type theory..can you please explain more about how this achieves the goals of the OP?

Comment: He wanted to have a constructor argument of the same type as a type member. class `AA` comes pretty close to that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, class `AA` looks very interesting indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Does this not suit your needs?

```
class A[T](ts: Seq[T])
```

Comment: It is what I am trying to move away from.  This is how my current implementation works, but I would like to think of Parameterized Types as being useful for something I need to make a lot of generic instances of (eg: List[String], List[Int], List[NyanCat], etc etc) rather than something that will generally have less than 10 use cases (eg: TV[NTSC], TV[PAL], TV[Digital]).